# An exception occurred: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException -- in Selenium RC

Tags: selenium

While I am trying to get the value from the text box, it's throwing No such element found issues,

below are my field properties:

> input id="altid" class="firstColumnInput text C1 disabled" type="text" value="100281"
>   securityidpath="MEMBER_DEMOGRAPHICS.INDICATIVE_INFORMATION.INDICATIVE_INFORMATION.PERSON.ALT_IDENTIFIER"
>   name="$EntryField$7" lockrequired="true" tabindex="-1"
>   readonly="readonly"

code for getting the value is:

> driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).getAttribute("value");

result:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":**"**//*[@id=\"age\"]"**}** For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.2.0', revision: '13073', time: '2011-07-25 19:23:22'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1',
>   java.version: '1.6.0_22' Driver info: driver.version:
>   EventFiringWebDriver

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

try using searching with xpath with the id of the input, something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"altid\"]")).getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for any element that has the attribute id = "age". Referenced by,

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=\"age\"]"}
```

The id for that specific input seems to be "altid", so you just have to use the proper id value.